# NoSQL: new kind of relationships using Arrays?

Tags: graph, many-to-many, relationship, couchbase, nosql

I had to manage relationships between documents over a NoSQL engine (Couchbase), and I figured out this way to solve my problem. Here is my solution and the steps that let me realize it:

https://forums.couchbase.com/t/document-relationships-using-arrays-and-views-passing-though-graph-theory/3281

My questions are:

- What do you think about this solution?
- Have you ever used something like this? How is it working?
- Are there any better ideas? Critical points of this solution should be helpful

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting post Matteo. After reading it I realized that you can possibly improve on few aspects:

- Consider 1-1 node relationships. In your post you focus on N-N node
  relationships (sure one can argue that 1-1 is a subset of
  N-N)...however I think there is a potential of having a different (optimized) implememgtaion for 1-1 relationships. for 1-1 I use node key
  value as a field in my json doc (e.g. user: {name:string, dob:date, 
  addressID:string})
- Node key design to address relationships: You can encode in the key
  value relationship information, e.g. key: "user#11", "user#11#address#123", "address#123#user#11", etc.
- Data integrity aspects: Take into consideration missing complex
  transactions. i.e. you can't mutate several documents in one
  transaction. The design should compensate for that.

I have used similar solution in my model design for Couchbase in the past. Its now in production for several years already and its performing just fine (load is about 250 tps)...I was trying to avoid as much as possible creating complex node relations and ended up having very few 1-1 and 1-N types.

Comment: Thank you for the effort, I had a response to my questions. Here are my considerations:

1. ok
2. ok, but I prefer to not map the logic inside keys
3. of course, that's the app job ;)

Comment: For point #2. I think you should evaluate pros/cons for keys having relationship mapping. In some cases I found it very powerful concept. For example one can synthetize a key to retrieve related node document while documents itself doesn't have reference to that node.

Answer (score 0):

I tested out this solutions and works well. I like the flexibility of the 'always possible' N-N relationships, because you can simply add the relationship document when you need it without changing the application logic. There is a drawback: you need to implement your own application logic constraints to avoid relationships abuse.

I noticed that using arrays there isn't a great advantage compared to JSON objects and sometimes it may be useful to have other relationships data, for example the weight (or cost) of the relationship. So I suggest you to use a relationship document that as it's own type:

```
{
  "type": "relationship",
  "documents": ["key1", "key2"],
  "all-the-data-you-need": { ... }
}
```

Looking at the performance there isn't so much difference using objects over arrays.

Hope this helps someone! ;)